# Why is Google Chrome not starting after replacing udev with systemd-tools?

Tags: google-chrome, arch-linux, udev

I recently updated my system via `sudo pacman -Syu`. Afterwards, I proceeded to open Google Chrome, but it failed. When I tried to start it via the terminal I got the error.

> /usr/bin/google-chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed it from AUR, reinstall (`yaourt -S`) and then it will work again.

A link to `/usr/lib/libudev.so.1.0.1` will be created in the `google-chrome` folder.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this error is because of the transition from `udev` to `systemd-tools`. During this update `/usr/lib/libudev.so.0` is renamed `/usr/lib/libudev.so.1.0.1`.

A nasty, dirty hack which just happens to work is to create a symbolic link from the later to the former. Like so.

```
# ln -sf /usr/lib/libudev.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/libudev.so.0
```

To clarify, *the solution* is to recompile the application so that it links to the new so, `/usr/lib/libudev.so.1.0.1`. Unfortunately, Google Chrome (as opposed to Chromium) is provided as a binary package, and therefore we are unable to recompile it, so for now, the nasty, dirty hack is the best we can do while waiting for Google to fix it.